# scrapy version 1 logging are not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, scrapy

I am using a script to initialise my spider,

#### note this is scrap version 1

```
def setup_crawler(domain):
    #spider = GeneralSpider(attributesXMLFilePath=domain)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    Settings.set(settings, 'JOBDIR', "SeenFolders/bla bla bla")
    Settings.set(settings, 'LOG_FILE', "LogFiles/bla bla bla.log")
    Settings.set(settings, 'LOG_ENABLED', "TRUE")
    Settings.set(settings, 'LOG_LEVEL', "INFO")
    crawler = Crawler(spidercls = GeneralSpider ,settings = settings)
    crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    #   crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(domain)
#crawler.start()

setup_crawler('Websitesbla bla bla.xml')
#log.start()
reactor.run()
```

after running my code, i can see the seen folder in the correct place, but there is no log file. Plus, i tried to log from the spider and nothing also appeared on the cmd (terminal)

plus inside the **init** of the spider, i tried to print

```
print("LOG_FILE ="+ str(myS['LOG_FILE']))
        print("JOBDIR ="+str(myS['JOBDIR']))
```

but the results are both of them null

#### note

everything was complete working as a beautiful when i was using scrap 0.24, but when i updated to scrapy 1 , i started having this problems.

#### Update

i am defining my logger as this

```
self.myLogger = logging.getLogger(self.name)
```

then i write as this

```
self.myLogger.error('The spider {0} with xml file = {2} starts working on {1}'.format(self.name,  datetime.datetime.now(), attributesXMLFilePath))
```